# Can I configure task manager to restart my computer on disconnection?

Tags: windows-10

I have a computer running windows 10 that does some operations for me remotely, but for some reason it randomly disconnects, and the only solution I have found is to restart the computer. Re-establishing the connection doesn't work most of the times. Is there a way for me to restart my this computer automatically whenever it disconnects from the internet?

Answer (score 0):

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | find "TTL=" || shutdown /r /f /t 0
```

Put this into Task Scheduler (or save as .BAT-file and shedule it), and set it to execute, for example, each minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a task using task scheduler upon disconnect. You can set this as a trigger. This way you can execute this without any checks.

The command to execute is `Shutdown`, the parameters are `/r /f /t 0`.

Do note, if you normally disconnect the pc, it will also reboot the machine.